# Чем смотреть логи error.log?

Tags: php, apache, логирование

При распаковке одного архива из десятка domain.ru.error.log.1.gz (173 мегабайта) он превращается в архив

По запросу гугла и яндекса "чем читать error.log" выводит всякую хрень уровня знаний где логи лежат и что их не прочитать

Нужно удобное средство под linux и windows, позволяющее смотреть их в realtime, в идеале через какую-то панель

Распакованный лог весит 4 гига, notepad++ его не открывает

Comment: Сегодня все экстрасенсы в новогоднем отпуске уже. Тут хотя бы уточнить чего именно логи читать то.

Comment: "Ищу программу", требования неопределённые ("чтобы мне было удобно") - такие вопросы сразу на закрытие. Автору могу дать несколько советов. Во-первых, выражаться тактичнее (хрень, делать нечего) и уважать собеседников. Во-вторых, настроить ротацию логов через 100 метров (чтобы файлы не пухли до 4 Гб). В-третьих, гуглить более точные вопросы: что спросили - то и выдаёт. Программ таких валом, разной архитектуры.

Answer (score 4):

Смотреть надо на сервере,

```
zless domain.ru.error.log.1.gz
```

а в реалтайме

```
tail -f domain.ru.error.log
```